# Makefile include env file

Tags: environment-variables, make

I'm trying to include some env vars into a Makefile. The env file looks like:

```
FOO=bar
BAZ=quux
```

Note there's no leading `export` to each env var. If I add the leading `export` and just `include` the env file in the Makefile, everything works as it should. But I need to keep the env vars sans leading `export`. That prevents me from just using `include envfile` in the Makefile.

I've also tried doing something like this:

```
sed '/^#/!s/^/export /' envfile > $(BUILDDIR)/env
include $(BUILDDIR)/env
```

But doing that cause make to throw an error because the env file isn't there for including.

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux. Please state the question you have clearly. What is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to include a file that contains environment variable pairs into a Makefile so that they are available to the environment in which make is running.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you are using gnu make, what should work is to include the `envfile` file, then
export the list of vars got from the same file:

```
#!make
include envfile
export $(shell sed 's/=.*//' envfile)

test:
        env
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's brilliant! Although my version even works without the `export $(shell...` line. I just need the `include` line.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you have any `$` in the env file make won't like them and you'll have to escape them. `PASS=Pass123$` will just show up as `Pass123`. This answer explains the caveats pretty well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637188/3384609

Answer (score 115):

I had a similar problem and landed on this thread.  Another possible solution is to just do the make export command without any arguments:

```
include .env
export
```

This will export all make variables as environment variables.  This behavior may or may not match all use cases, but it worked for me and didn't involve any shell scripting wizardry.

Comment: For better backwards compatibility, I'd recommend setting the `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:` special target instead of using the `export` directive, as described here in the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html

Comment: Worth to hint that if `.env` doesn't exist, GNU Make will raise `.env: No such file or directory`

Comment: Doing `-include .env` will prevent the error, which may or may not be the desired result

Comment: This creates infinite recursion in make >=4.4 as in this exmample: https://github.com/photoprism/photoprism/discussions/3790 How do you fix it?

Answer (score 10):

To complete previous anwswer from `meuh`, if you would like env file to be dynamic, you could define a setup function.

- create `env/local-dev.env`,`env/integ.env` file with some content
- define a method to load this

```
    define setup_env
        $(eval ENV_FILE := env/$(1).env)
        @echo " - setup env $(ENV_FILE)"
        $(eval include env/$(1).env)
        $(eval export sed 's/=.*//' env/$(1).env)
    endef
```

Then use it

```
    localDevEnv: ## load env/local-dev.env environment
        $(call setup_env,local-dev)
    integEnv: ## load env/integ.env environment
        $(call setup_env,integ)
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 10):

an example of how you can use .env values in Makefile

```
#!make
include .env

migrateinit:
    migrate create -ext sql -dir mysql/migrations -seq int_schema

migrateup:
    migrate -path mysql/migrations -database "mysql://${DB_USER_NAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@tcp(${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT})/${DB_NAME}" -verbose up 1

migratedown:
    migrate -path mysql/migrations -database "mysql://${DB_USER_NAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@tcp(${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT})/${DB_NAME}" -verbose down 1
```

Answer (score 8):

Preserves pre existing ENV vars

```
export $(shell [ ! -n "$(ENVFILE)" ] || cat $(ENVFILE) | grep -v \
    --perl-regexp '^('$$(env | sed 's/=.*//'g | tr '\n' '|')')\=')

test:
    echo $$FOO
```

To run

```
make ENVFILE=envfile test # bar

export FOO=foo
make ENVFILE=envfile test # foo
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an elegant solution that does not import Make vars, but does set any environment exports for shell subprocesses. Personally I prefer to keep my profiles dynamic scripts.

```
export BASH_ENV=tools/sh/env.sh
```

There are some gotchas. Unfortunately ENV does not work, I think it should (but that's an issue with Bash, not Make). Also it really requires another line, because Make's default shell interpreter is /bin/sh.

```
BASH_ENV := tools/sh/env.sh
SHELL := /usr/bin/bash
```

On the up-side this also allows to include shell functions in Makefile scripts, but only for the recipe scripts. I don't know how other shells besides Bash fare. And there is a bit more going on. [I put some testfile up as GIST](https://gist.github.com/dotmpe/3edab10ac041c8fbbeb3c4b6e37109cc).

There are plenty of complicated shell scripts imaginable. I like this Q/A best for the simple answers.

Comment: reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Invoked-non_002dinteractively

Answer (score 6):

if your filename is `.makerc` then you can include it to Makefile as simple as this:

```
include .makerc
```

I prefer to add `-` sign before `include`, to suppress any warnings.

Comment: I can't verify this on make 4.2.1. without export after the include.

Answer (score 1):

If you have bash, you can use `allexport` option before loading a `.env` file.

```
# sample usage:
#   $ make from-env RECIPE=another-recipe
from-env:
    bash -c 'set -o allexport; source .env; set +o allexport; make "$$RECIPE"'

another-make-recipe:
    printenv
```